# Adding Fields to JSON in better way Javascript

Tags: json, node-red

I'm using Node-Red and the data is passed using JSON objects. 
All of the data is in msg.payload. I want to add a new property, the TimeStamp,  to the object without all of this unnecessary code...It works but I know this is sloppy.

Is there a better way?

```
var TimeStamp = new Date();

var newMsg = [ ];

newMsg.push({payload: 
                      { TimeStamp:TimeStamp , 
                        Humidity: msg.payload.Humidity,
                        Temperature: msg.payload.Temperature,
                        CO2: msg.payload.CO2,
                        Light: msg.payload.Light

                      }

            });

return newMsg;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the new property to the existing `msg` object and pass it on.

```
msg.payload.TimeStamp = new Date();
return msg;
```

This is the better approach as it leaves all other message properties untouched.

Comment: Thanks bro, I tried all of these weird ways and it was so simple.